# Java: When to clear an Observable Object

Tags: java, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I have and Observable object with following object being shared:-

```
HashMap<String,HashSet<String>> data;
```

I have a `put` function which appends entries in the above data and notify the observers after getting enough data.

```
put(String k, String line){
    if (!data.containsKey(key)) {
        addNewKey(k, line);
    }else{
        data.get(key).appendToList(deviceid);
    }
    if (data.get(key).size() > writeSizePerList || data.size() > writeSizeLists || System.currentTimeMillis() > lastDumpTimestamp + waitTimeMillis) {
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
        lastDumpTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

However I am stuck in the function. I need to clear the data object once all the observers have already processed after notify call. How would I capture this event? I can't keep adding data due to scalability issues.

**Edit:**
Problem remains even if we don't clear it. How will we handle the race condition where `put` function wants to change the data put observers are still reading it because of previous notification? How to handle speed mismatch between observer and observable?

Comment: makes no sense ... why are you storing it if all you want to do is send it to your observers anyway and then clear it?

Comment: @Constantin Looks like I am misunderstanding the design pattern here. Isn't this pattern designed to simplify the addition of new observers?

by removing the unclear option, don't you think that we  are limiting observable data to primitive data types only? Because in case of say, HashSet, how would observer know the diff? 

I have edited my question. This problem will remain even if we are not clearing it.

Comment: you can make your put method synchronized so nothing is put into your collection until the entire method is complete (all observers get a consistent look of the same set)